# Php.exe in CMD throws "Call to undefined function oci_connect()"

Tags: php, cmd, oracle-call-interface

I have XAMPP installed with PHP 5.2.6 in Windows XP. In my php.ini I have the next lines uncommented:

- extension=php_oracle.dll
- extension=php_oci8.dll

I have a file with something like this:

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');

?>
```

But when I try call to php.exe through cmd to that file, the console always give me an error:

> **Fatal Error:** Call to undefined function oci_connect()

In my localhost I have no problem with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you're not looking at the right php.ini file for the command line.

In php.exe, run:

```
echo phpinfo();
```

then look for the php.ini path at the top.

Comment: You're right, thanks!! I was changing C:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini, but checking with phpinfo() made me see that php.exe uses C:\xampp\php\php.ini